# Factory pattern - choosing using static method

Tags: python, factory-pattern

I want a Factory Pattern in my python code for two different files formats.
Is it OK to define a static method to choose my new class, without defining **init** or **new** in the base class?

something like:

```
    Class Field(fileName):

       @static method
       def chooseClass(fileName):
            if '.grb' in fileName:
              return FieldGrib(fileName)
            if '.nc' in fileName:
              return FieldnetCDF(fileName)
            else:
              raise valueError('File format not supported')
```

And is it possible to dynamically allocate the new class as soon as Field(fileName) is called, without calling any of the methods?

The answers below do solve my problem, but I end up with a recursive loop with super, could you help me point out the problem?

```
    class Field(object):

def __new__(cls, fieldFile):
    if '.grb' in fieldFile:
      return FieldGrib(fieldFile)
    else:
       raise ValueError('no support for other formats')

def __init__(self, fieldFile):
    print fieldFile

class FieldGrib(Field):

def __init__(self, fieldFile):
    # read Field, opening fieldFile if required
    super(FieldGrib, self).__init__(fieldFile)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In regards to your second question, I don't believe it is possible to do what you want without using **new** unless you are ok with making it a function like fferri describes. What you can do is this if you want to maintain the class structure.

```
Class Field(object):
    def __init___(self):
        pass

    def __new__(cls, filename):
       if '.grb' in fileName:
          return FieldGrib(fileName)
        if '.nc' in fileName:
          return FieldnetCDF(fileName)
        else:
          raise valueError('File format not supported')

class FieldGrib(Object_To_Inherit_From)
    def __init__(self, fileName):
        super().__init__(fileName)
        self.fileName = fileName
        ...etc.
```

EDIT:

If you want to maintain functions from the base class you can change the inherited class on the FieldGrib class and the FieldnetCDF class as those are what is returned from the factory class.

EDIT 2:

You cannot inherit from the factory class because when you call super it will run **new** again, entering a recursive loop. The factory class is simply that, a factory. It should not inherit from anything. It simply dictates which class to return. FieldGrib and FieldGrib should inherit from the class that contains the functionality you want, not from Field. If field is only ever used to create other things you can create a private Field class called

```
class _Field(object):
```

that contains the functionality you want and can be inherited from. It shouldn't be called directly though.

This would turn FieldGrab into

```
class FieldGrib(_Field):
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *factory pattern* code looks ok.

For "dynamically allocate the new class as soon as Field(fileName) is called", you can simply do:

```
def Field(fileName):
    if '.grb' in fileName:
        return FieldGrib(fileName)
    if '.nc' in fileName:
        return FieldnetCDF(fileName)
    else:
        raise ValueError('File format not supported')
```

or if you really need `Field` as a class for some reason, you can use `__new__` as follows (make sure Field is a [new-style class](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass), i.e. if using Python 2, inheriting `object`):

```
class Field(object):
    def __new__(cls, fileName):
        if '.grb' in fileName:
            return FieldGrib(fileName)
        if '.nc' in fileName:
            return FieldnetCDF(fileName)
        else:
            raise ValueError('File format not supported')
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. That's quite simple, but I want to retain my BaseClass as some methods are common for the two subclasses. Is there any other way out?

Comment: @I.K. I updated my answer with an alternative solution